# Amazon S3 Upload PDF and Create Cover Image

Tags: php, pdf, amazon-s3, imagick

I have the following bit of code which uploads a PDF to Amazon S3, what I need to do is create an image from the 1st page of the PDF and upload that to s3 as well.

```
//instantiate the class
$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

//check whether a form was submitted
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    //retreive post variables
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $extension=end(explode(".", $fileName));
    $rand = rand(1,100000000);
    $sha1 = sha1($rand);
    $md5 = md5($sha1);
    $fName = substr($md5, 0, 20);       
    $finalName = $fName.'.'.$extension;

    //create a new bucket
    $s3->putBucket("bucket", S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    //move the file
    if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "bucket", 'publications/'.$finalName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
        $s3file='http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/'.$finalName;
        $aS3File = 'publications/'.$finalName;

        $im = new imagick($s3file[0]); 
        // convert to jpg 
        $im->setImageColorspace(255); 
        $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG); 
        $im->setCompressionQuality(75); 
        $im->setImageFormat('jpeg'); 
        //resize 
        $im->resizeImage(640, 877, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);  
        //write image on server (line 54) 
        $s3->putObjectFile("","bucket", 'publications/'.$im->writeImage($fName.'.jpg'), S£::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    }else{
        echo "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";
    }
```

I have replace my actual bucket name with 'bucket' for security, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here as I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message
>   'Unable to read the file: h' in
>   /var/www/ams/pub-new-issue.php:45\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/ams/pub-new-issue.php(45): Imagick->__construct('h')\n#1
>   {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/ams/pub-new-issue.php on line 45,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s3file='http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/'.$finalName;
$im = new imagick($s3file[0]);
```

`$s3file` is a string, but you're accessing an array index in it. As a result, you fetch the first character, `h`. Use just `$s3file` in your Imagick instantiation and you should be fine.

Comment: did as you said here but got the following error

**Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/var/www/ams/d4cf8f3e33c27055fcb3.jpg':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587' in /var/www/ams/pub-new-issue.php:54\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/ams/pub-new-issue.php(54): Imagick->writeimage('d4cf8f3e33c2705...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/ams/pub-new-issue.php on line 54**

Comment: Does `/var/www/ams/d4cf8f3e33c27055fcb3.jpg` exist? Is it accessible by the webserver user? Where is that path coming from, anyways? `$s3file` should be `http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/...` per your code.

Comment: /var/www/ams is the root folder of this application and therefore I would assume that it is accessible. I have only dropped the [0] as you suggested so I am unsure as to where it is getting this?

Comment: Hard to tell, as you've removed some code from the example, so knowing which line is #54 is difficult. Is it the `$im->writeImage($fName.'.jpg')` line? If so, your webserver probably doesn't have permissions to write the image to that location. You should write to a temporary file, probably.

Comment: line 54 is $s3->putObjectFile("","bucket", 'publications/'.$im->writeImage($fName.'.jpg'), S£::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

Comment: OK, so your web server isn't able to save to the Imagick object to `/var/www/ams`. Try putting it in `/tmp` or something.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help me, I am not trying to store this image locally but save it to Amazon S3. Is there anything in that original paradigm that I can do to solve this.

Comment: Your code `$im->writeImage` stores the image locally. If you're not trying to store it locally, stop trying to store it locally.